# Non-union-affiliated shop steward

Tags: phrase-requests, legalese, business-language

I'm looking for an English word or short phrase to convey a meaning which is similar to “union representative” or “shop steward”, except that the person in question is not (necessarily) associated with a union. That person is an employee of a company who is elected by his fellow employee to represent him in various relations with the employer.

The point is to distinguish between two concepts in French labor relations: a “*[délégué syndical](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9l%C3%A9gu%C3%A9_syndical)*” (lit. “union representative”), and a “*[délégué du personnel](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9l%C3%A9gu%C3%A9_du_personnel_en_France)*” (lit. “representative of the workforce”). While it is possible for a *délégué du personnel* to also be a *délégué syndical*, they are separate roles, and the *délégué du personnel* does not have to be a union member, and even if he is he does not speak for the union in his role as a *délégué du personnel*.

[IATE](http://iate.europa.eu/iatediff/SearchByQuery.do) is decidedly unhelpful here, suggesting only “shop steward” and “trade union representative” for *délégué du personnel*, both of which are wrong. [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/d%E9l%E9gu%E9+du+personnel.html) offers suggestions, but none that strike me as clearly making the difference between union and union-agnostic representatives. There evidently is no similar concept in labor relations in English-speaking countries, so I'm looking for a good enough approximation.

What would be a good way to translate *délégué du personnel* into English (taking care not to imply a union representative)? A way to describe this role in a sentence or two that makes sense to UK and US audiences would be appreciated too.

Comment: I think the world has moved on a bit since those two French terms were introduced. [All forms of closed shops in the UK are strictly illegal under section 137(1)(a) of the Trade Union and Labour Relations (Consolidation) Act 1992](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_shop), for example. Ordinarily the workers choose their own representatives, and there are often several different unions relevant to a workforce. It wouldn't be impossible for a dozen workers at one site to all belong to different unions, yet have a representative who wasn't a member of *any* union.

Comment: Translation is listed as off topic in the FAQ.

Comment: @MετάEd Um, what? This is a phrase request, not a translation question. It so happens that my goal is to translate a French phrase, but I explained the meaning of that phrase in English, you don't need to know any French to understand the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Perhaps in the UK, but in the US a shop steward is still (by law) an elected worker representative who is also a member of a union.

Comment: @Mark: I don't seriously expect to understand the American perspective on such matters. When checking Wikipedia to find out when we banned the closed shop in the UK, I noticed [The Taft-Hartley Act outlawed the closed shop in the United States in 1947](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_shop), but I very much doubt we're talking about the same kind of legislation in the same social/labour relations context (we might be a *bit* behind the US in some respects, but surely not 45 years! :)

Comment: @Gilles "What would be a good way to translate *délégué du personnel* into English” is plainly a translation request. The problem with translation requests is not just that they require familiarity with the source language but also that, as this question exemplifies, there often isn’t a clear right answer, which means the answers received will be overly subjective.

Comment: Could you use a word like *emissary*, which means "an agent sent on a mission to represent or advance the interests of another" or a *go-between*, meaning "one who acts as an intermediary or messenger between two sides"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers (severely off topic, I know, but) In the US, whether union shops (similar to a closed shop) are allowed varies from state to state. About half the states allow union shops, about half don't. I agree that trying to understand 51 different legal systems operating simultaneously is enough to make one's head explode, and furthermore is probably why we need so many damn lawyers over here. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general term for this is *staff representative* or *staff rep* for short. This can be used for any person who represents staff and need not be a member of any union (although they may).

If it really must be stressed the person is not a union member, I'd got for *non-union [staff] rep*.

Answer (score 3):

As you say, I don't think there is a well-established word for it. I would go for *workers' representative*, but it will need a bit of explanation exactly what is meant.

Comment: I don't really see that *workers'* (or *staff*) *representative* needs any further explanation along the lines of "(who isn't a union member)". If most of the workforce happened to be female/coloured/young/whatever, that wouldn't imply we needed separate words for representatives who did (or *didn't*) fall into that category themselves, or that you would for some other reason be likely to need to convey that information.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it does need clarification in my context, because the context involves both union representatives and workers' representatives.

Comment: I have also seen "workforce representative". @FumbleFingers, the distinction does make a difference in the US

Comment: @Gilles,Mark: I think maybe this is a "social" US/UK difference. But where it's necessary to distinguish the two people in Britain, I think you'd just call one the *workers' representative*, and the other a *union representative* (where the latter might or might not be significantly endorsed by the majority of the workforce).