# What is a term for a non-union labourer?

Tags: single-word-requests

A **union worker** is to **clergy** as **x** is to **laity**. Is there a more encompassing term than **non-union** worker.

"The city was fined for contracting non-union workers."

Comment: Uhmm, Union laborer.

Comment: _Nonunion workers_ is normal, and there is no more-encompassing term because this is the counterpoint to _union workers_. Sometimes _scab_ (a derisive, contemptuous, & judgmental term), but scabs can be union workers who work for non-union wages & on nonunion jobs with less than union-prescribed working conditions.

Comment: Also see  [Non-union-affiliated shop steward](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94183)

Comment: If one supposes clergy are not unionized, then x=clergy is a reasonable solution for “union worker : clergy :: x : laity”.  Note, question organizations that could evoke x=non-union are “union worker : x :: clergy : laity” and “union worker : x :: laity : clergy”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no better word.  The opposite of *union* is *non-union*, and these two sets have no members in common. However, their own union is the universal set: everyone is either one or the other, never both.

Answer (score -1):

I'm in a a union that negotiates for everyone, including the non union members. We refer to them as free-riders.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. *Free-rider* may be suitable among union workers in the situation you describe, but that is a distinct minority of workplaces. Most workplaces are non-unionized small businesses, and organized labor has little presence or influence in dentist's offices, mom-and-pop delis, or cell phone repair kiosks. *Free-rider* would be rather inaccurate.